# magento get products per page for category list

Tags: php, magento, collections

how can i get the setting 
[image]

> products per page on grid allowed values

or the setting

> products per page on grid default value

so i can limit the collection

my current code is

```
    public function getLoadedProductCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($this->getCategory());
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPage(0,?); // i need the value from one of the settings above
    $collection->load();
    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Products per page on grid allowed values:

```
$allowedValues = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page_values');
```

Products per page on grid default value

```
$defaultValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');
```

Using default value, your code should look like:

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($this->getCategory());
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPage(0, $defaultValue);
    $collection->load();
    return $collection;
}
```